# Using Parse-Server locally with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, parse-server

I have Parse-Server running locally on one laptop and I'm trying to access it using JavaScript from a second laptop.  I can access Parse-Server just fine using the follow curl command from the 2nd computer using terminal:

```
curl -X POST -H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APPID123" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"score":1341,"playerName":"P MUR","cheatMode":false}' http://192.168.1.16:1337/parse/classes/GameScore
```

BUT, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same with JavaScript.  Here's the code that's not working:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script src="//www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.6.14.min.js"></script>
<script>
Parse.initialize("APPID123");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://192.168.1.16:1337/parse/classes/GameScore';

var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new gameScore();
gameScore.save({playerName: "Pete"}).then(function(object) {
  alert("yay! it worked");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried everything I can think of.  thanks!

Comment: There can be some problem with your `Parse`  javascript library . Please port error/problem also whatever you are getting .

Comment: Code doesn't report an error, the browser just doesn't show anything and new GameScore is not posted.

Answer (score 0):

Your Parse server url should just be the root URL:

`Parse.serverURL = 'http://192.168.1.16:1337/parse/';`

The JS client will construct the final URL (with `/classes/GameScore`) for you.

Comment: That's what the the Parse docs said to use.  That was the first thing I tried and it didn't work.  So, I tried duplicating the full address as used in the curl command.  Still wouldn't work.

Comment: You also have `var gameScore = new gameScore();` instead of `var gameScore = new GameScore();`

Comment: Hey, thanks for that.  Corrected and still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Caught it.  I needed:

```js
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

DMan was also correct.  Works fine now.  I'm not sure why jQuery is needed in this code, but, hey, whatever works.  Thanks all!!

Here's the code that works:

```js
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-latest.js"></script>
<script>
Parse.initialize("APPID123");
Parse.serverURL = 'http://192.168.1.16:1337/parse';
var GameScore = Parse.Object.extend("GameScore");
var gameScore = new GameScore();
gameScore.save({playerName: "Pete"}).then(function(object) {
  alert("yay! it worked");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```